# How to create simple addition in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have a simple iPhone project open in Xcode.
In the storyboard file i have a view controller with :
2 text fields
1 label
1 round rect button

What I am trying to do is the following:
Have the user enter any number in field A, then the same on field B. 
Then once the "Submit" button has been pressed, I would like the app to add the two values.

So far this is the code that I have but I am currently stuck as I am getting an error on build.

My Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface ADDViewController : UIViewController



@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *valueA;

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *valueB;



@end
```

My Implementation File:

```
#import "ADDViewController.h"



@interface ADDViewController ()

- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberA;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberB;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLabel;



@end



@implementation ADDViewController



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization

    }

    return self;

}



- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {



    self.valueA = self.numberA.text;

    self.valueB = self.numberB.text;



// THE FOLLOWING IS WHERE I AM CURRENTLY GETTING AN ERROR WITH XCODE: 
// XCODE SAYS : INVALID OPERANDS TO BINARY EXPRESSION ('NSSTRING *' AND 'NSSTRING *')

    NSString * total = self.valueA + self.valueB;

}

@end
```

And this is a screen shot of my story board file:

http://i43.tinypic.com/352q98i.jpg

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must convert your strings to numbers (e.g. using `intValue` or `floatValue` methods), add those two numbers, and then convert the resulting `sum` back to a string. You can't perform numeric operations on strings, themselves.

You could, therefore, do something like:

```
CGFloat a = [self.numberA.text floatValue];
CGFloat b = [self.numberB.text floatValue];
CGFloat sum = a + b;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
self.answerLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(sum)];
```

Comment: I really appreciate it, thanks Rob!